# Moving to the requested page in uiscroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 4 pages in my scroll view and I have 4 buttons. If the user pressed the first button, I want to jump to page 1, and so on with the remaining three buttons. I don't know how to do this.

```
myview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:myview];

scroll1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll1.pagingEnabled = NO;
NSInteger numberOfViews1 = 8;
float h = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews1; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.height;
    printf("%f\n",xOrigin);
    scrollview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,xOrigin, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scrollview1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1-h green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
    [scroll1 addSubview:scrollview1];
    [scrollview1 release];
    h = h + 0.2f;
}
scroll1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height * numberOfViews1);
[self.view addSubview:scroll1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scrollRectToVisible:animated: if you know the y-coord where each page starts inside the scrollview.